# reading offline Maildir archive with graphical email client

Tags: email

I have an archive of old emails in `Maildir` format. The directory (let's call it `my_archive`) has proper `Maildir` structure

```
$ ls ./my_archive
cur  new  tmp
```

I am able read the emails with `mutt` by specifying the mailbox to load:

```
mutt -f ./my_archive
```

Mutt is OK, but I would like to read the archive with a graphical email client, so that I can easily work with attachments.

Is there some similar way to open my archive in some email client like Thunderbird?

Comment: Here's a list of [mail readers that support maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir#Mail_readers).  Apparently, sylpheed also has [a plugin](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/sylpheed-claws-maildir-plugin.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just install an IMAP server on your local machine, point it to these archives, and configure it as another account in your favourite graphical MUA.

I'm running an `uw-imapd` on my workstation at work to get synchronised access to local mail folders between text client (`pine`, in my case) and graphical client (`kontact`, in my case), since our company's new eMail hoster (G**gle) doesn't manage to get IMAP folders working right, and because I sometimes need to archive yet still access eMails that contain sensitive information.